# simple scroll event not firing in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am new to Vue and am trying to get the simplest scroll event handler set up. For some reason, it is not firing at all.

In my component, I have:

```
mounted () {
 window.addEventListener('scroll', this.runOnScroll);
},

methods: {
 runOnScroll () {
   console.log('scroll!');
 },
},
```

This is so basic, I don't understand why runOnScroll isn't firing!

Comment: This works fine for me. I just tried it on https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/play/ 

There must be some error that has occurred in your component that caused it to silently break. Vue (at least in my experience) tends to swallow up errors that occur at critical parts of component rendering and it will lead to unresponsive components. What happening when you run this config in a component? Do you get an error or does it seem like absolutely nothing at all is happening?

Comment: Nothing at all will happen.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your window is tall enough to actually be able to scroll.  If you just want to listen for when the user uses the mouse wheel, listen for the `wheel` event instead.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.runOnScroll);
    window.addEventListener('wheel', this.runOnWheel);
  },

  methods: {
    runOnScroll() {
      console.log('scroll!');
    },
    runOnWheel() {
      console.log('wheel');
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
  <div>hello world!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me figure that it was onWheel that I was after - for capturing scroll even without any overflow on the parent container. Thanks!

Comment: this works for me didn't know there was a wheel event.
arigato

Answer (score 1):

overflow auto was my issue.. after removing it, both wheel and sroll worked like a charm

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/problem-with-scroll-event-v-on-scroll-method-not-fire/48040/4

Comment: just want you to know that this comment saved my ass.... thanks a bunch!